# How To detect Image Orientation & skew In ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv

I want to detect Image Orientation & skewing and rotate the image to be ready For scanning using OCR. how to do in ObjectiveC

Comment: not _really_ a C++ question...

Comment: @Nick i tried openCV Library but i have problems with integration with ObjectiveC

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can use any OCR which can detect the Text orientation then you can find the correct image orientation...

Comment: You are totally wrong. Which OCR can detect angles? Tesseract doesnt.

Answer (score 4):

You could use another library than openCV that supports the required operations.

First use erosion followed by a hugh transformation to find the angle to the x-axis as demonstrated [here OpenCV - Detect skew angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/category/opencv/page/2/) in order to rotate the image.

The orientation could be estimated by checking width / height (rotate 90°) and test run of the OCR library. In case of a low  detection rate you could rotate (180°) and run OCR again.

Comment: Thank You very much Stacker, i think this will Solve the problem

Comment: what is the value width / height (rotate 90) ?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim The width and height of your input image in pixel I though of Paper_size http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size